# Resizing and Watermark Image in C#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, image-resizing, system.drawing

i want to watermark pictures with different sizes in one folder. the watermark has 3891 x 4118 pixels. the pictures i want to watermark have nearly the same size or way lower.

however, the watermark image should always have the same size on the images. therefore i take the width of image i want to watermark, multiple it by  0.2 (20%) and the height of the watermark image gets calculated by the ratio. (see code below).

after that, i resize the watermark image and put it on on the image i want to watermark. so far so good, but the problem is, that the image is way smaller than it should be. the calculation works fine, even if i say, put the image as is (3891 x 4118 pixel), it calculates it correctly, but the watermark doesn't get bigger. it stays on a size i didn't calulcate.

that's the button to load the folder.

```
 private void DateiLaden_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();


            try
            {
                string[] files = GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath.ToString(), "*.jpg|*.jpeg"); //Only select JPG pictures, method below

                int anzahlBilder = files.Length;
                if (anzahlBilder <= 0)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No images!");
                } // if there are no images, stop processing...
                else
                {
                    var res = checkImageSize(files); //check if they have a minmal size, method below
                    if (res == "") //if everythings fine, continue
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(fbd.SelectedPath.ToString() + "\\watermarked"); //create new directory of the selected folder, folder so save the watermarked images


                        System.Drawing.Image brand = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("../../watermark.png"); //load watermark
                        double imageHeightBrand = Convert.ToDouble(brand.Height); //get height (4118px)
                        double imageWidthBrand = Convert.ToDouble(brand.Width); //get width (3891px)
                        double ratioBrand = imageWidthBrand / imageHeightBrand; //get ratio (0.94487615347)

                        foreach (var file in files)
                        {
                            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file); //load image to watermerk to get width and height

                            double imageHeightBild = Convert.ToDouble(img.Height); //height of the image to watermark
                            double imageWidthBild = Convert.ToDouble(img.Width);  //width of the image to watermark                 

                             //Landscape
                             if (imageWidthBild > 640.0 && imageHeightBild > 425.0)
                             {
                                 var imageWidthTmpBranding = imageWidthBild * 0.2; //the watermark width, but only 20% size of the image to watermark
                                 var imageHeightTmpBranding = imageWidthTmpBranding / ratioBrand; //height of watermark, preserve aspect ratio

                                 int imageWidthBranding = Convert.ToInt32(imageWidthTmpBranding); //convert in into int32 (see method below)
                                 int imageHeightBranding = Convert.ToInt32(imageHeightTmpBranding); //convert in into int32 (see method below)


                                 var watermark = ResizeImage(brand, imageWidthBranding, imageHeightBranding); //resize temporally the watermark image, method below

                                 System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file); //get image to watermark
                                 Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image); //load is as graphic
                                 g.DrawImage(watermark, new System.Drawing.Point(50, 50)); //draw the watermark on it
                                 image.Save(fbd.SelectedPath.ToString() + "\\watermarked\\" + returnOnlyImageName(file)); //save it in the folder with the same file name, see method below.
                             }

                            //Portrait
                           /* if(imageWidthBild > 350 && imageHeightBild > 520) {

                            }*/

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(res);
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

"methods below"

```
 private static string[] GetFiles(string sourceFolder, string filters)
        {
            return filters.Split('|').SelectMany(filter => System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, filter)).ToArray();
        }

        private static string checkImageSize(string[] files)
        {

            string message = "The following pictures are too small:\n";


            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Bitmap img = new Bitmap(file);

                var imageHeight = img.Height;
                var imageWidth = img.Width;

                if ((imageWidth < 640 && imageHeight < 425) || (imageWidth < 350 && imageHeight < 520))
                {
                    message += returnOnlyImageName(file) + "\n";
                }
            }

            if (message == "The following pictures are too small:\n")
            {
                return "";
            }
            else
            {
                message += "\nPlease change those pictures!";
                return message;
            }

        }

        private static string returnOnlyImageName(string file)
        {
            return file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("\\")+1);
        }

        public static Bitmap ResizeImage(System.Drawing.Image image, int width, int height)
        {
            var destRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
            var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

            destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
            {
                graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
                {
                    wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                    graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
                }
            }

            return destImage;
        }
```

and is it also anyhow possible to save all the watermarks in the bottom right corner?

thanks in regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go...

```
void waterMarkOnBottomRight(Image img, Image watermarkImage, string saveFileName)
    {
        double imageHeightBrand = Convert.ToDouble(watermarkImage.Height);
        double imageWidthBrand = Convert.ToDouble(watermarkImage.Width);
        double ratioBrand = imageWidthBrand / imageHeightBrand;

        double imageHeightBild = Convert.ToDouble(img.Height); //height of the image to watermark
        double imageWidthBild = Convert.ToDouble(img.Width);
        var imageWidthTmpBranding = imageWidthBild * 0.2; //the watermark width, but only 20% size of the image to watermark
        var imageHeightTmpBranding = imageWidthTmpBranding / ratioBrand; //height of watermark, preserve aspect ratio
        int imageWidthBranding = Convert.ToInt32(imageWidthTmpBranding); //convert in into int32 (see method below)
        int imageHeightBranding = Convert.ToInt32(imageHeightTmpBranding);

        int watermarkX = (int)(imageWidthBild - imageWidthBranding); // Bottom Right
        int watermarkY = (int)(imageHeightBild - imageHeightBranding);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img)) 
            g.DrawImage(watermarkImage,
                new Rectangle(watermarkX, watermarkY, imageWidthBranding, imageHeightBranding),
                new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)imageWidthBrand, (int)imageHeightBrand),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        img.Save(saveFileName);
    }
```

This one's working for landscape (width > height).

Well.. in your code, you don't have to create separate instances for images for calculating, for creating graphics, add a new bitmap and paint using graphics and all. You do anything with the image, its in the memory. And its not going to affect the watermark image on your disk.

Comment: i used your method, and it works very well! thanks again! i call the method in a loop, because i want to watermark a whole folder, right? if there are about 40 images in that folder everything works fine, but lets say i want to watermark about 100 images, i get an outOfMemoryException. Solution for that: switch the application to x64. but i also need a x86 app, do you also know a solution for that problem?

Comment: Not 100 but you can even do 1000 or 2000

Comment: just make the local variables as global, reassign their values when reading back the function. Thats all.

Comment: Cauz when you call the function again and again a new memory space is conceived. But if you make it global, the same memory space is recycled.

Comment: I read me through Global Variables, but still it doesn't work...
maybe you could still help me, my current code: http://pastebin.com/CwrQ42ce
thank you very very much in regards

Comment: Saw your codes. Are you using both the lines **Image img = Image.FromFile(pathofimg);** and **GlobalVariables.setImageToWatermarkPath(pathofimg);** same time?

Comment: Got it.. Just remove the line **img = Image.FromFile(pathofimg);**

Comment: No, of course, i tested it without Image img = Image.FromFile(pathofimg); But still, it throws an SystemOutOfMemoryException
I know I'm like hell asking and asking for help, and I'm really really thankful for your help!!!! 
Dropbox Link to Project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dj8muwyb2018462/FotoExpressNeuSo.zip?dl=0 that's my written project, maybe if you want to, you give a look by yourself... there is also a screenshot inside....